# Grouping and sub Total in data table C# ASP.NET

Tags: group-by, grouping, subtotal

I have a DATA Table :

```
                COLUMN:  City    Deposittype  DepositAmount                  
                ROWS :  city1     new          100
                        city1     new          200
                        city2     old          200
                        city2     old          100
                        city2     new          200
                         city3    new          100
```

Want to Group by city, calc sum of depositamount for specified Deposittype.

Example, for condition depositType= new

i want a row like

```
               city1 city2 city3
                300   200   100
```

I want sum of DepositAmounts Grouped by City with specific Deposit type. i.e Result row should have city1 city2 city3 as column names, under which sum of 'Depositamounts' for a specified loan type say Deposittype = new.

Comment: so have you tried anything yet?

Comment: it has to be done in C# only. Im trying to do with LINQ. First time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, SUM(DepositAmount) FROM myTable
WHERE Deposittype = 'new'
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: He need the result in one row.

Comment: Need the result in that format( ROW ) for a few specific Deposit types. And finally i will merge all those rows into a table. which is my final result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
   (
    SELECT SUM(DepositAmount) FROM myTable 
    WHERE Deposittype = 'New' AND City = 'City1'
   ) AS City1,
   (
    SELECT SUM(DepositAmount) FROM myTable 
    WHERE Deposittype = 'New' AND City = 'City2'
   ) AS City2,
   (
    SELECT SUM(DepositAmount) FROM myTable 
    WHERE Deposittype = 'New' AND City = 'City3'
   ) AS City3

FROM    myTable
```

Comment: I have to do this in c# only. either using LINQ or querying table.

Comment: This is a dynamically created table. Thats why